# LAPACK will not make

Tags: software-installation

Following earlier advice/posts:

LAPACK
Download the latest version of LAPACK
tar -xvf lapack-3.9.0.tar.gz
cd lapack-3.9.0/
cp make.inc.example make.inc  # use example make as make
make
cp *.a path/to/lib

When I tried to 'make' everything seemed fine until I got:
recipe for target 'znep.out' failed
Error 139, and then:
recipe for target 'lapack_testing' failed
Error 2.
Please help.

Comment: Probably this: [Segmentation fault when testing xeigtstz](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/issues/276)

Answer (score 1):

Your method is unnecessary. LAPACK is [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/lapack), use the command below to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked.